# WP_Query fails despite having 1 post

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

I'm doing a typical custom post type query with args like this:

```
array (size=4)
  'post_type' => string 'custom_post_type' (length=15)
  'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
  'posts_per_page' => int 5
  'p' => string '2943' (length=4)
```

Yet amazingly, despite the fact that there IS one post being queried (and it *does* exist) I get a `false` in the loop for have_posts

What strange phenomenon is responsible for this? There IS 1 post!

```
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        //...
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        //more dots ... dot dot dot ...
        endwhile;
        //...
    else:
        echo 'No stuff found ... dot dot dot';
    endif;
```

Comment: I don't understand the first block of code. Your loop fails because your arguments for `WP_Query` is not valid

Comment: The first block is just a var_dump($args) ... but what part is not valid?

Comment: is the post published? If the post is like trashed or draft. The query will return empty. Also what do you see when dump `$wp_query->posts`. As you are using `p` make sure ID is right? If only one ID you can use `get_post()` instead.

Comment: You've got it - I'm using p to get a single post. p should probably be used with get_post()

Comment: What do you get if you dump `$wp_query->post_count`?

Comment: Oddly enough I get "null" (using the query I have in above post)

Comment: Looking at the results of your `var_dump( $args );` at the top of your question, I have a couple questions: Is your custom post type *named* `custom_post_type`? Are you positive that the post with ID `2943` is of the type `custom_post_type`? Does your query return anything if you change your `$args` to this: `$args = array( 'p' => 2943 );`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T a look at how to properly construct a query with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
   $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'cameras',
   'posts_per_page' => 5,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You should go and have a look at how you registered your [post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). Apart from that, how are you using your query on your page. Do have one query, or multiple queries. If you have have multiple queries, you can have problems with your query. Also, as said before, check your post_status of your post.

If you need to cal only one particular post, you can just do the following, not necessary to use the other statements for post type

```
$args = array(
       'p' => 2943,
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

At this stage it is impossible to pin point a problem. Just a tip, flush your permalinks again

Comment: Am I missing something? I have those two items.

Comment: If my answer doesn't do it, you should let me know and then also [file an edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/149501/edit) and add your template code and the code how you registered your post type :-)

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? Was my answer or the other answer useful in solving your problem. If yes, please accept the appropriate answer. If your problem is not solved, where is our code lacking. If you solved your own problem it would be nice if you post that as an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `have_posts()` and `the_post()` with the object operator. Edit your code thusly:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
        //...
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        //more dots ... dot dot dot ...
        endwhile;
        //...
    else:
        echo 'No stuff found ... dot dot dot';
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) :
```

If you're doing this inside a function or some other piece of code, then your $wp_query is not the same $wp_query that the main Loop functions ( like have_posts() ) are actually looking at.

The main Loop functions use the global $wp_query instance, which is the main one generated by WordPress for the main Loop. That one probably is empty for your case.

What you should do is more like this:

```
$my_custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $my_custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
   while ( $my_custom_query->have_posts() ) : $my_custom_query->the_post();
```

And then your various Loop functions will work properly, because now you're loading the_post() from your custom query.